# A cube build with cuboids

Tags: geometry, three-dimensional, tiling

You are given 27 pieces of 1x2x4 cuboids. Is it possible to build a 6x6x6 cube using those 27 cuboids?

Comment: Do you want theoretical or empirical answers? I think theoretical would be better.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, I believe that it is

> Impossible

Because

> [image]
>
>  Using this diagram, each cuboid will cover **exactly one** RED X.
>  As there are $28$ RED X, thus we need at least $28$ cuboids which is not possible.

Comment: Surely, this is a very nice and unique tiling puzzle nevertheless! :D

Comment: I believe this doesn't prove that it is impossible. There could be a placement with 27 X.

Comment: We could place 27 X or even less, but recall this will act as a lower-bound of the number of pieces needed.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky After placing 26 cuboids, you will have filled exactly 26 of the Xs. The space you have left cannot be filled with the 27th cuboid since it contains two of the Xs.

Comment: I do not believe you have proven your point.  No piece can cover more than one X **per image**, but that doesn't say one piece can't cover an X on two different faces.

Comment: @LorenPechtel The images are not faces, they are layers, stacked on on the other. If you look closely you will see that the cuboids can't double up on x's even between different layers.

Comment: You won't be surprised that my tiling program agrees with you. 2 mins 38 secs to confirm no packing exists. I suspect that this was set by someone some years ago as a size that was pretty much 'out of reach' of a brute force search.

Comment: Here is an equivalent but slightly different colouring argument. Think of the 6x6x6 cube as being built from 27 2x2x2 blocks. Give this a checkerboard colouring, so that there are 14 white blocks and 13 black ones. Every cuboid piece, however it is placed, will consume an equal amount of the two colours. You will therefore always have 8 unfilled white spaces.